# Is there a JSF component that supports autocomplete and can hold multiple values?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm developing an application in JSF 2.0.
I was wondering if there is a JSF component that supports an autocomplete function and that can hold multiple values (that binds to an array or a list). I don't have the time and knowledge to create such a component myself.

I know PrimeFaces has got the `p:autoComplete` (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf) component, but it can only 'hold' one value. I'd need a component that can do what `p:auotoComplete` does, but multiple times; the textarea should be able to display multiple values. Is there a library that contains such a component?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to find some JQuery plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest PrimeFaces snapshot 3.1 got [AutoComplete - Multiple Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteMultiple.jsf)

You can get it from here

[3.1-SNAPSHOT](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.1-SNAPSHOT/)

Answer (score 1):

You might see this [Richfaces example](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&sample=cachedAjax&skin=wine). I think that *tokens* and *autoFill = "false"* will work.